# Distribution of a variable and glm family

Tags: r, regression, distributions, generalized-linear-model

I have one variable that it is a continuous variable (>0) with decimals, that is a lab measurement. This corresponds to the intensity of fluorescence that is related to the concentration of DNA.
First, I thought that Poisson could work because it is counting (concentration) but I have values like 234.34 because it is an intensity of fluorescence...

```
summary(mydata$DNA_reservoir)
##Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##0.00    6.65   48.35   80.89  112.50  323.10
```

[image: density plot]

I want to design a model glm in which I have to see the association between other variables (cont and cat) with this DNA_reservoir. Any ideas of what family to use?

Comment: The *marginal* distribution of the response is irrelevant to model choice; what matters is what the GLM models -- the *conditional* distribution. You can't assess that from this. Can you describe how fluourescence relates to the counts you mentioned? Are the data really discrete (even if not integer-valued)?

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b for your response. The response variable is a concentration (I don't know what you mean for really discrete, you can have 0.4 or 56.43 but not -2). The DNA concentration is calculated on how much intensity per volume the machine reports so is totally related. Did I answer your question?

Comment: That helps, thanks. You do have readings that are exact zeros? Or are they just small readings that are showing up as 0 to the 3 figures R is showing?

Comment: They are both exact 0 and small readings

Comment: Do you mean "There are..." rather than "They are"? ... You have to be careful of the spike of exact zero values, as models like gamma, lognormal, Weibull don't model exact 0's.  One option is to model the occurrence of 0/non-zero and then model just the positive values. Either part (or both parts) of the model can rely on predictors.